# REDIRECT_URI_MISMATCH with Azure AD B2C Web App (Python/Flask based)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-webapps

I am using Azure AD B2C to incorporate user identities/ auth into a pre-existing web app (Python/Flask deployed via Azure App Service).

I followed the instructions in  [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-app-python?tabs=app-reg-ga) . Got it to work just fine on my local machine using http://localhost:5000/getAToken as the redirect URI.
However, when I deploy this to our test/ stage server and change the redirect URI to the equivalent: *https://stage.mywebsite.com/getAToken*  , I get the a redirect uri mismatch error when trying to invoke the Login user flow:

*The redirect URI http://stage.mywebsite.com/getAToken provided in the request is not registered for the client id ......*

The app is deployed as *https only* so not sure why the redirect uri being constructed uses http.

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the new Redirect URI `https://stage.mywebsite.com/getAToken` in your app registration also? If not try updating this new redirect_uri in your app registration, as AAD would match the entry in your redirect URI to the value in the redirect_uri section on your App registration in AAD.